# Looking for a Code Text Box library in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, xhtml

I am looking to add a functionality to a simple HTML where you can display your code and be able to view the plain text and print it also.

It also formats the code accordingly for brevity.

I was looking to similar to this [site](http://biemond.blogspot.com/2009/03/some-handy-code-for-backing-beans-adf.html).

But I am not sure what are the free options available that I could include as JavaScript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-javascript-syntax-highlighting-scripts/

or:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/11-syntax-highlighters-to-beautify-code-presentation/

google for 'syntax highlight' ...